# How to add complex data type from Groovy script to the response in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, response, extract, soapui

My question is about putting data elements (from groovy script) in the response in SoapUI.
I've an array of data that I would like to put in my response (in different tags/elements)

---

I'm aware of putting a simple element like this:

The element "**MyName**" in the Xml response:

```
<ns:MyName>${MyName}</ns:MyName>
```

Is mapped from the Groovy script by

```
context.setProperty("MyName" , "My name" )
```

---

Now the problem:

my Xml response looks like this:

```
   <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:GetDataSummaryResponse>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns:GetDataSummaryResult>
        <ns:DataSummary>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <ns:DataSummaryResponseDetail>
              <ns:Name>?</ns:Name>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <ns:DataProgress>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <From>?</From>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <Procent>?</Procent>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <To>?</To>
                 <!--Optional:-->
```

In Groovy I've built data array which is filled with data for example like this:

```
context:[DataSummary:[DataSummaryResponseDetail:[Name:My  name, DataProgress:[From:some text, **Procent:some value**, To:some text]]]
```

In the response I'm able to see the whole value of `${DataSummary}` but how do I get the element "**Procent**"

I maybe am wrong about how to build my context data, but feel free to adjust!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with a lot of searching.
First of all, I needed to use "=" in front of the element to be able to get a handle like
${=DataSummary[0]}
This works on the top level of my data shown before.

But to really solve the problem I created a Class in Groovy like this:

Code: Select all
    Class DataSummaryResponseDetail {
    public String name
    public DataProgress DataProgress = new DataProgress()
    public Value[]  value =  new Value[2] 
    }
    class DataProgress {
    public Date From
    public Date To
    public float Procent
    }
    class Value {
    public String Currency
    public int Amount
    }

```
def hsrd = new DataSummaryResponseDetail()
hsrd.name = 'Some name'
hsrd.value[0]=new Value()
hsrd.value[0].Amount = 1000
hsrd.value[0].Currency = 'SEK'
hsrd.totalValue.Amount = 2000
hsrd.totalValue.Currency = 'USD'
```

and then in the response xml. I refer to elements like this
${hsrd.value[0].Amount}
${=hsrd.totalValue.Amount}

def hsrd = new DataSummaryResponseDetail()
hsrd.name = 'Some name'
hsrd.value[0]=new Value()
hsrd.value[0].Amount = 1000
hsrd.value[0].Currency = 'SEK'
hsrd.totalValue.Amount = 2000
hsrd.totalValue.Currency = 'USD'

Problem solved. If you know of a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with SoapUI, but have you tried this:

```
${DataSummary.DataSummaryResponseDetail.DataProgress.Procent}
```

If DataSummary is an array, you could access the first entry using

```
${DataSummary[0].DataSummaryResponseDetail.DataProgress.Procent}
```

You can iterate over the array using the method each(), so

```
${DataSummary.each { it.DataSummaryResponseDetail.DataProgress.Procent }}
```

would get you all entries.

Comment: Nope!

Since DataSummary like many other stuff here are "arrays", I need a way to declare which index I'm interested in.

Comment: Thanks for our reply. 
As I wrote earlier I build an array in Groovy But the data is included in the xml response like this"[DataSummary:[DataSummaryResponseDetail:[Name:My name, DataProgress:[From:some text, Procent:some value, To:some text]]]" also as string.

I've tried the simpler variants as follow but I'get no value back.
${DataSummary[0].DataSummaryResponseDetail[0].Name}
${DataSummaryResponseDetail[0].Name}

If I use "${DataSummary}" I get back the whole string. Does it have anything with XPATH to do to reach the data I need?
Do I have to build my Context(DataSummary) another way?